# NHibernate query parameter parser throws an error on '/*[1]/@type' expression

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate, special-characters

I have a table in a database and one of the columns contains xml stored as nvarchar. I need to write a query and get information based on data stored in that column.

So I ended up writing the following native sql query using NHibernate:

```cs
string sql = @"SELECT a.id as s
   FROM [DBT].[dbo].[tb_myTable] a
   where (cast (a.vchExtendedInfo as XML)).value('/*[1]/@type','NVARCHAR(MAX)')='deal'"
ISQLQuery sqlQuery = HibernateUtil.GetCurrentSession().CreateSQLQuery(sql)
```

And it throws an error: 'ArgumentOutOfRangeException' - Length cannot be less than zero.Parameter name: length.

After a little bit of testing I found out, that NHibernate is trying to parse my query and that `'/*[1]/@type'` line is probably the cause. *(This is actually a simplified example and all other conditions work nicely if I remove this one)*.

So, how do I escape/fix my query to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is because of the "@" in the query.

Did you already try using parameters?

```
string sql = @"SELECT a.id as s
   FROM [DBT].[dbo].[tb_myTable] a
   where (cast (a.vchExtendedInfo as XML)).value(:type,'NVARCHAR(MAX)')=:value"
ISQLQuery sqlQuery = HibernateUtil.GetCurrentSession()
  .CreateSQLQuery(sql)
  .SetAnsiString("type", "/*[1]/@type")
  .SetAnsiString("value", "deal");
```

Comment: Well I've spent quite a lot of time on this problem. I ended up having an error where xml.value function refused to accept parameter as a first value and only accepted string literals. I've even copied the code generated by NHibernate into SQL Studio and tried to make it work there. The last semi-working solution was where I've used sql.variable[] wildcard and it wasn't giving me errors but the query yielded wrong results(empty query).

Comment: The only working solution using NHibernate was to create a dynamic SQL string and pass it to sql along with exec command. But we had some concerns about dynamic SQL perfomance under heavy load so in the end I just ended up ripping underlying connection from NHibernate session and wrote my statement using ADO.NET as my colleague suggested. And it works perfectly fine.